# CloudKit endpoint SSL certificate hostname issue

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, cloudkit

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.5.2 to make CloudKit Web API requests. When I send requests to the CloudKit endpoint URL (https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/[...]), I get the following error:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <api.apple-cloudkit.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.icloud.com]`

I'm no expert on SSL, but it looks like Apple is serving a certificate for `api.apple-cloudkit.com` that's only valid for `*.icloud.com`. Am I understanding that right?

Or if the certificate is correct, then why is HttpClient complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the library you use or the underlying platform does not support [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Without SNI you get:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.apple-cloudkit.com:443 | openssl x509 -text
...
Subject: CN=*.icloud.com,
```

But when using SNI you get a different certificate:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.apple-cloudkit.com:443 \
   -servername api.apple-cloudkit.com | openssl x509 -text
...
Subject: ...CN=cdn.apple-cloudkit.com
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
  DNS:api.apple-cloudkit.com, DNS:cdn.apple-cloudkit.com
```

Older versions of the Apache HTTPClient library are known to have missing support for SNI so make sure you use a recent version.